# Generate compiler warning with user defined annotation

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations, warnings

Is it possible for make the compiler generate a warning when it encounters a user defined annotaion? Something similar to the `@Deprecated` annotation?

Thanks

Comment: Why should it be possible, a custom annotation is fairly legal? The warning for @Deprecated is built-in functionality. Look at your IDE whether it provides built-in support for custom static code analysis...

Comment: @home : I want to annotate methods in which I've done some coding but commented it cause it's not required at the moment. Don't want to keep searching for it later on. It should be clearly visible when browsing through the code. I'm using Eclipse Helios. Is it possible to do the code analysis on it? I wasn't able to locate it. Thanks

Comment: Why not use the //TODO tag in your comments?  Eclipse will gather them all into a task list for you.  They're also highlighted in blue along the right edge of the editor window.  (Warnings are highlighted in yellow.)

Comment: @jkeeler: the auto generated code in eclipse also adds the todo tag. a lot of developers forget to remove the tag after they've coded. so there are a bunch of useless todo's in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your original question and comments, I assume you're trying to do the following:

- Mark code as incomplete (with a compiler warning) so other developers do not use it yet.
- Identify the incomplete code in your IDE at a later point in time.

I don't believe you can mark the code with a compiler warning.  The `@Deprecated` tag is baked into the compiler.  A more common way of indicating a method is incomplete is by throwing an exception:

`throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");`

The effect isn't realized until runtime, but the other developers **should** be unit testing their code.

As for identifying the incomplete code I would still refer back to my original comment.  Use the `TODO` comment tag and Eclipse will build a task list for you.  If your list is cluttered with auto-generated code that hasn't been cleaned up, you can use `FIXME`, `XXX`, or define your own.  You should then be able to filter your list.

Answer (score 2):

I've asked the Lombok people to look at providing this functionality https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/issues/114 and it is now implemented ;-) https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/%40Warning

Answer (score 1):

It's possible via annotation processors api

Here is Lightweight Javac Warning Annotation library https://github.com/pushtorefresh/javac-warning-annotation

Usage:

```
// some code...

@Warning("This method should be refactored")
public void someCodeWhichYouNeedAtTheMomentButYouWantToRefactorItLater() {
    // bad stuff going on here...
}
```